# Polling MBeans Attributes with out refresh

Tags: java, jmx, visualvm

This is what I did:

**Step 1:** Exposed MBeans Attributes:

[image]

**Step 2** Polling Options

[image]

What else do I have to?

Still I don't see attribute values getting updated without clicking on refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double-click on the value (for example 129.0 in your screenshot) and you will get the graph with live data. There is no need to set 'Ordered key property list'.